# Update an ear file in Tibco Administration

Tags: tibco

I created an ear file using tibco designer and deployed it in the administration.Its working fine.Now i want to add one more process to the current ear file .Please suggest me to do this.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

In TIBCO Designer, just add your new process in the archive, build a new EAR file from this archive then upload the new EAR file in TIBCO Administrator.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply,...By doing this the new ear file appears as new application in tibco administrator.I want to add a new  process to the currently running service instance.

Comment: You need to upload your EAR file over the existing application deployed in TIBCO Administrator, then redeploy the application, as described in acop's response.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of steps to follow:

1. add new process to archive in Tibco Designer
2. build new EAR file
3. go to Tibco Administrator
4. find your application in Application Management
5. go to Configuration part under your application
6. click on your application name on Configuration Builder panel (it should be in first row of the panel)
7. click on Upload EAR
8. then regular: Browse and OK
9. in Confirmation dialog: OK
10. in next dialog push: Save
11. and you should be again on screen with Configuration Builder: now your app should be marked as Deployable
12. push Deploy
13. select 2 checkboxes

    - Stop running services before deployment
    - Start successfully deployed services

That is the whole procedure.

Comment: Thankq so much,..i got it.